# ¿Como solucionar el error "Attribute android: layout_width is not allowed here"?

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

[image: **Esto es lo que me aparece**]

Por favor, ayudenme!, y perdon por los errores en mi publicacion, soy nueva en esto. Los errores que aparecen son los siguientes:
* Attribute android: layout_width is not allowed here
* Attribute android: layout_height is not allowed here
* Attribute tools: context is not allowed here
* Element TextView is not allowed here

El código es este:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.admin.lala.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Por favor ayudenme!, y de antemano gracias! :)

Comment: lograste solucionar este error? tengo este mismo error, desintale el android 3.1.4 e instale el 3.0 y persiste el mismo error, si encontraste la solucion a este error estaria muy agradecido que lo compartieras , para asi poder avanzar, saludos

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso lo solucioné cambiando en el build.gradle

"compileSdkVersion 27" ...y "targetSdkVersion 27"

por

"compileSdkVersion 28" ...y "targetSdkVersion 28"

y sincronizando, vuelve a reconocer android:"loquesea"

(pero tendrás que actualizar las versiones de las dependencias que estés utilizando y quedaran atrás.)